# pass secure socket as normal socket in boost

Tags: c++, boost-asio, shared-ptr

I have these typedefs the problem is I need pass a secure socket as TSocket will a direct cast from TSecureSocket to TSocket work ? or is there another solution? depending on the port I will make the socket secure and in others I will not. I just need the return type to be TSocket.

```
  typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket            TBoostSocket;
  typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<TBoostSocket>  TSLLSocket;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<TBoostSocket>         TSocket;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<TSLLSocket>           TSecureSocket;
```

I have looked at this 
[boost::asio convert socket to secure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699766/boostasio-convert-socket-to-secure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have these typedefs

```
  typedef boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket            TBoostSocket;
  typedef boost::asio::ssl::stream<TBoostSocket>  TSLLSocket;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<TBoostSocket>         TSocket;
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<TSLLSocket>           TSecureSocket;
```

> the problem is I need pass a secure socket as TSocket. Will a direct
>   cast from TSecureSocket to TSocket work ?

Short Answer No. Because `boost::asio::ssl::stream<TBoostSocket>` wraps the socket.

> or is there another solution? depending on the port I will make the
>   socket secure and in others I will not I just need the return type to
>   be TSocket.

However `TSLLSocket` (or boost::asio::ssl::stream rather) provides a method for retrieving the socket from an instance:

```
const next_layer_type & next_layer() const;
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/next_layer/overload1.html

Where `next_layer_type` is defined by the following typedef:

```
typedef boost::remove_reference< Stream >::type next_layer_type;
```

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/next_layer_type.html

Since you define your template with `TBoostSocket` that is what you should get when you call `next_layer()` or `lowest_layer()`

Of course this returns a reference not a pointer, and that reference is to an instance not owned by you. So you will now need to somehow wrap this in a shared_ptr, and that may not be that easy since you can't allow it to be deleted.